# CheckedTreeSelectionDialog not selecting parent

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using `CheckedTreeSelectionDialog` to display fields in a class. If i select an item in the child tree, the parent node does not get selected. Is this the way it works? If i want the parent node to be selected automatically, when i select a child node what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this method? It might be what you want. 
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/CheckedTreeSelectionDialog.html#setContainerMode(boolean)